# AJAX with different dataType

Tags: jquery, ajax

PHP-application has form loaded via AJAX as Bootstrp's Modal.
This form sends as html

```
 type: 'post',
 dataType: 'html',
 data: $('#form-client').serialize(),
 cache: 'false',
 processData: 'false',
```

but the respond may be as html (when some fields have error and needed request again) and as json (when success).
When respond is JSON I am unable get the properties of the respond. If I change `dataType: 'html'` to `dataType: 'json'` I am unable to get html page when error is occur (form validation).

What is the solution? Thanks.

Comment: Why not just return html inside JSON like this: `"html" : "<div . . . whatever . . ."`

Comment: Hmm. This is one of solutions

Comment: You can also 1. try to parse JSON 2. catch the error if it was html 3. treat the field like html. This approach is described here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20743326/jquery-ajax-returned-data-json-and-html-mix